# What is different between Opacity, Visibility and Display in css?

Tags: css

I am confused with these three terms which are used in CSS. What is different between Opacity, Visibility and Display in CSS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Display**:

- Can't be read by screenreaders. If you put `display: none` on your body tag, your page will never popup in the Google result, because Google sees it as a blank page.
- height = 0
- width = 0
- animatable: no

**Visibility**:

- Can be read by screenreaders. If you put `visibility: hidden` on your body tag, your page will popup in the Google result, but a visitor will just see a blank page
- height = initial;
- width = initial;
- animatable: no

**Opacity**:

- Can be read by screenreaders. If you put `opacity: 0` on your body tag, your page popup will in the Google result, but a visitor will just see a blank page;
- height = initial;
- width = initial;
- animatable: yes